# ffmpeg -vsync deprecated, use -fps_mode

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, sync, switch, ffmpeg-filters

I used to use -vsync -1 to Auto Sync a Audio and Video input stream using the -copy switch as they would get out of sync at times and sometimes not so can't specify any seconds for a delay setting but I am getting this message now -vsync deprecated, use -fps_mode but I can't find any information on this new -fps_mode switch. Does anyone know how to use it to Auto Sync an Audio and Video stream? I'm running it in Windows, Thanks

Comment: Look for `fps_mode` in [FFmpeg Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#:~:text=%2Dfps_mode%5B%3Astream_specifier%5D%20parameter%20(output%2Cper%2Dstream)). It looks like `-fps_mode -1` is the same as `-vsync -1`. `auto (-1)` - *Chooses between cfr and vfr depending on muxer capabilities. This is the default method.*. Note that `-vsync` is deprecated, but we can still use it.

Comment: Got it, Thank you

Comment: Hello, I'm using "-fps_mode auto" but the stream will still get out of sync after a few days. Is the word auto in the Document just explaining what -1 does? So my command should be -fps_mode -1 instead of -fps_mode auto? When I use -1 I get the error: Invalid value -1 specified for fps_mode of #0:0. What does it mean Stream Specifier? -fps_mode[:stream_specifier] parameter (output,per-stream)

Comment: If it's getting out of sync after a few days, my guess it that is unrelated to `fps_mode` (but I don't have any experience with videos that takes days). Try `vfr` and `passthrough`... The `stream_specifier` is relevant in cases where there is more than one video stream - it allows us to define different `fps_mode` for each video stream. `-fps_mode:0:v` applies the video from the first input file. `-fps_mode:1:v` applies the second input file... `-fps_mode:0:v:0` applies the first video stream of the first input file `-fps_mode:0:v:1` applies the second video stream of the first input file...